# What is the difference between fct_unique and unique?

Tags: r, forcats

What is the difference between the functions `unique()` and `fct_unique()`? There does not seem to be any difference other than `fct_unique()` only works with factors, whereas `unique()` works with all variables, categorical and numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the difference already mention in the question that `fct_unique` only works with `factors`, other difference is the way they return the output.

```
f <- factor(c('a', 'x', 'b', 'b', 'y', 'r'))
f
#[1] a x b b y r
#Levels: a b r x y

forcats::fct_unique(f)
#[1] a b r x y
#Levels: a b r x y

unique(f)
#[1] a x b y r
#Levels: a b r x y
```

`fct_unique` returns output in order of the factor levels whereas `unique` returns in the order of their occurrence in the vector.

Comment: Interesting...and thank you for sharing! It is a distinction, but very subtle.